# Getting permission denied when use makemigration in django

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, makemigrations

I am using a docker file to handle my django app. I added user to the docker file as following:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13
LABEL maintainer="H.Bazai"

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
COPY requirements.dev.txt /tmp/
COPY app /app/
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

ARG DEV=true
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        build-base postgresql-dev musl-dev zlib-dev jpeg-dev && \
    apk add --no-cache postgresql-client postgresql-dev jpeg && \
    python -m venv /py && \
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
    if [ $DEV = "true" ]; then \
        /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.dev.txt ; \
    fi && \
    rm -rf /tmp/* && \
    apk --purge del .build-deps && \
    adduser \
        --disabled-password \
        --no-create-home \
        hbazai && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/media && \
    mkdir -p /vol/web/static && \
    chown -R hbazai:users /vol && \
    chmod -R 755 /vol

ENV PATH="/py/bin:$PATH"

USER hbazai
```

Then I build it. "docker-compose build".
Up to here everything is ok.

Then when I use the bellow command to makemigration, I got the error of ' permission denied '.

The command:
docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations"

The Error:

```
Creating recepie-api-django_app_run ... done
Migrations for 'core':
  core/migrations/0005_recipe_image.py
    - Add field image to recipe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 190, in handle
    self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 228, in write_migration_files
    with open(writer.path, "w", encoding='utf-8') as fh:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/core/migrations/0005_recipe_image.py'
ERROR: 1
```

I would appreciate it if somebody can help me out.

I tried many things to give permission to the user of my ubuntu. (chown and chmode)
but I still get the error.

Comment: Try with chmod -R 777 /vol.

Comment: try with rootuser or sudo

Comment: In this project it is important to do not use the root user. So I must give the permission to the current user (hbazai)

Comment: @ManishGupta it doesn't work.